# firebase schema structure for a lot of children

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase project is growing fast and I have a lot of children in some paths (the structure is kept flat as possible).

```
my tree looks like this
/client/section
-key: value
-key: value
...
```

In some sections I've got 80k+ children and growing fast (I could easily hit 1mil+ in a few months). I was thinking of splitting the sections into `section1, section2,...` but the problem is that I have to do the `numChildren` (which of course loads all the children) check before I insert another child (to keep the section inside the desired limit).

Another idea was to change the `section` to date `Y-m-d` or just `Y-m` but that would again generate a lot of paths.

With the new schema I'd also like to add some properties to the current children (so I have to do some work on the schema anyway).

Another idea was to feed this data into a relational DB.

I'd like you input on how to structure the schema for the future.

Thank you!